# how to add certificate to POD/Container 's cert store when root filesystem is read-only

Tags: c#, kubernetes, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-aks

I have a `.net core` application which is dockerized and running in Kubernetes cluster (AKS).

I want to apply securityContext `readOnlyRootFilesystem = true` to satisfy the requirement `Immutable (read-only) root filesystem should be enforced for containers`.

> securityContext:
> privileged: false
> readOnlyRootFilesystem: true

For `.net core app` I want to read TLS certificate and want to add into POD/Container's certificate store and to do this in startup I have below code,

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(File.ReadAllText(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("cert_path"))));
                AddCertificate(cert, StoreName.Root);
```

The problem is when I set `readOnlyRootFilesystem = true`, I am getting below error from the app,

> EXCEPTION: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The X509 certificate could not be added to the store.
> ---> System.IO.IOException: Read-only file system
> at System.IO.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(String fullPath)

It's saying for read only file system I can't add certificate. Is there a way to overcome this problem?

**Update**

If I set `emptyDir: {}`, I am getting below error? Where I can add it?

`spec.template.spec.volumes[0].csi: Forbidden: may not specify more than 1 volume type`

```
          volumeMounts:
        - name: secrets-store
          mountPath: /app/certs
      securityContext:
        privileged: false
        readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
        allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 1000   
  volumes:
  - name: secrets-store
    emptyDir: {}
    csi:
      driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
      readOnly: true
      volumeAttributes:
        secretProviderClass: azure-kvname
```

Comment: Did the solution of programmerq help you?

Comment: No. I am using the secret volume using in conjunction with CSI driver. If I try to add  mptyDir: {}. it's giving error: spec.template.spec.volumes[0].csi: Forbidden: may not specify more than 1 volume type

Comment: Check the `update` section of my question.

Answer (score 4):

At the location you have defined as the path of the cert store, attach a volume that is not read-only. If you only want that data to last as long as the pod exists, an [emptyDir](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir) type volume will fit the bill nicely.

For example, if you are creating pods with a deployment like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: ct
  name: ct
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ct
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ct
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: myapp
        name: myapp
        env:
        - name: cert_path
          value: /etc/certstore
        securityContext:
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
```

You could set up the emptyDir as follows:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: ct
  name: ct
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ct
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ct
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: myapp
        name: myapp
        env:
        - name: cert_path
          value: /etc/certstore
        securityContext:
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/certstore
          name: certstore
      volumes:
      - name: certstore
        emptyDir: {}
```

Other types of volumes would work as well. If you wanted to persist these certificates as your pods are cycled, then a persistentVolumeClaim could be used to get you a persistent volume.

The emptyDir won't be read-only, but the rest of the container's root filesystem will be, which should satisfy your security requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using `CSI Secret Driver` along for volume mounting and here is my configuration, `volumeMounts:
            - name: secrets-store
              mountPath: /app/certs`

Comment: now when I try to set emptyDir, `volumes:
      - name: secrets-store
        emptyDir: {}
        csi:
          driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
          readOnly: true
          volumeAttributes:
            secretProviderClass: azure-kvname` I am getting error, `spec.template.spec.volumes[0].csi: Forbidden: may not specify more than 1 volume type`

Comment: I can't remove `readOnly: true` for above csi driver, otherwise it's giving different error, `MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "secrets-store" : rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = Readonly is not true in request`

Comment: You would definitely need to set the emptyDir to be an emptyDir and not a secret. secrets are read-only by nature. an emptyDir is just a directory where you will have write access.

Comment: I agree sir, but do we have any solution where to put `emptyDir `. See my try in `update` section of question and error. Thanks.

Comment: You would use only the emptyDir and not your csi section. Look at the example I provided for how an emptyDir is defined. I included no other options for that volume beyond name and emptyDir. you should do the same.

Comment: @programmerq The issue I'm running into is by putting an emptyDir at the location of the certstore (etc/ssl/certs for alpine), it then wipes out anything that was at that location, including the existing certificates. 

Also, the path pointed to by the error thrown by AddCertificate for me is app/.dotnet rather than the cert store path, but mounting an empty directory there didn't solve that either.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the solution suggested by [programmerq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4930423/programmerq) looks fine.

As for this error:

> spec.template.spec.volumes[0].csi: Forbidden: may not specify more than 1 volume type

Once upon a time I got this error because I have tried to start a specific volume type, but went back to `emptyDir` using `kubectl apply`. However, the **old volume still existed** on the server side. `kubectl` tried to combine two volume specifications, which caused a problem.

On [this site](https://unofficial-kubernetes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) you can find an explanation:

> - If the admission plugin is turned on, the administrator may specify a default  `StorageClass`. All PVCs that have no  `storageClassName`  can be bound only to PVs of that default. Specifying a default  `StorageClass`  is done by setting the annotation  `storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class`  equal to "true" in a  `StorageClass`  object. If the administrator does not specify a default, the cluster responds to PVC creation as if the admission plugin were turned off. If more than one default is specified, the admission plugin forbids the creation of all PVCs.

See also [this question](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/48285).

Make sure your volume is created correctly, the old one does not exist and then try the solution suggested by [programmerq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4930423/programmerq).

Comment: Thanks @Mikołaj Głodziak. My volume is NOT a persistence volume. I delete my POD deployment and try to create again POD with emptyDir, but still same error.

Comment: If I removed CSI part in YAML `csi:
      driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
      readOnly: true
      volumeAttributes:
        secretProviderClass: azure-kvname`, then there is NO error.